# Installing Ruby on Rails Application with Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bash, centos

I want to install one Application on my CentOS 5.5 which requires Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5.

I have installed REE from [rubyenterpriseedition.com](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/). To install my application I need to do some settings. 
In my `.bash_profile` I should change `PATH = $PATH:$HOME/bin` to

```
PATH=/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

then to reload

```
source .bash_profile
```

To check whether changes have been reflected, we must run which gem. This has to output output:

```
/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/gem
```

But Unfortunately it is outputting

```
[root@local ~]# which gem
/usr/bin/which: no gem in (/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/college/bin:/root/bin)
```

After that when i do

```
[root@local ~]# gem update --system
bash: gem: command not found
```

I am getting above error.
But Look at the Actual PATH Below...

```
[root@local college]# echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/sbin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/college/bin:/root/bin:/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin
```

Please help me out to install this application on my CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up versions. I see both 2011.03 and 2012.02 mentioned. Please check which version you actually installed and make sure your PATH variable has this version as well.

Comment: HI, Maran. Thanks ... thanks a tonn for replying. I have Corrected my question. It was typo error. I have installed RUBY ENTERPRISE EDITION 1.8.7 FROM rubyenterpriseedition.com . MY Problem remains the same. Please tell me how to add gem path so I can successfully run the command gem update --system 1.3.7... Please help  –

Comment: Just a few more things: Did you run source .bash_profile from your home folder? To be sure use ~/.bash_profile. Please make sure gem actually lives in /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin (ls /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/)

Comment: Hi Maran, i have run source.bash_profile from my home folder... Still no use... I have tried the above installation on Ubuntu, centos and fedora... That too in different versions of these os's... I'm stuck very badly. I cannot move ahead unless gem lives in /opt.ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/...

Comment: In short what i can do so when I type WHICH GEM my system should output opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin.... Please help..

Comment: Please run ls /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2012.02/bin and give me the output.

Comment: Hi maran... I have installed ubuntu 13 and now everything is working fine... Sorry for late reply... Thanks for the support.

Comment: hi maran, I have another problem.... here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/q/24107692/3671149 Please help