# Rails 2.3.5 applications on Ruby 1.8.7 Rake Error.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to install Rails 2.3 gem on my Fedora server. The application is not having Gemfile in it. It requires `oauth2` gem. When I use the installation command it is giving the following error:

```
rake aborted!
can't activate rack (>= 1.1.0, < 2, runtime) for ["faraday-0.5.7", "oauth2-0.1.0"], already activated rack-1.0.1 for ["actionpack-2.3.5", "rails-2.3.5"]
```

Is there any way to find what are the required gems for the Rails 2.3.5 gem?

Comment: Why Rails 2.3.5, it's severely outdated.

Comment: try `rake gems:install` - if that doesn't work check the config/environment.rb file and manually install what is listed

Comment: If you're running Rails 2.3 you need to be at 2.3.18 or you're at [**severe** risk](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/3/18/SEC-ANN-Rails-3-2-13-3-1-12-and-2-3-18-have-been-released/).

Comment: Hi, my application is not having a Gemlfile. So there are no listed Gems. I don't know what are the server requirements/Required Gems  to install this application. Developers have kept the application open but they have not given the installation instructions for the app. I am having rails version 2.3.5. Please help.

Comment: Do you know if your Rails 2.3 app has bundler? If the app doesn't, it won't have a Gemfile and the app's gems will probably be located in config/environment.rb